# How dynamically filled multidimensional vector without a priori known its dimension c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, stdvector

I'm writing a class for tensors, I need it for my work. I figure out how to create dynamic multidimensional vector using recursion, but I don't know how to stretch it to dimensional size what I need (like this `vector<double> vec; vec.resize(6);`). But I want to get dynamic vector and have created template class.
Could someone help me with it? This is my code:

```
template<typename T,size_t N>
struct tensor_traits 
{ 
     using type = vector< typename tensor_traits<T,N-1>::type>; 
};
template<typename T>
struct tensor_traits<T,0> 
{ 
     using type = T; 
};



template<class T,size_t N>
class tenzor
{
protected:
    typename tensor_traits<T, N>::type data;
    vector<size_t> dimensions;
public:
    tenzor()
    {
        dimensions.resize(N);
    }

    tenzor(vector<size_t> dim)
    {
        if(dim.size() == N)

        {
            dimensions = dim;
            data.resize(dim);
        }
        else
            throw::length_error("wrong format!!");
    }

    void resize(vector<size_t> siz)
   {
    //some code`enter code here`
   }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need something so complicated rather than just to use a std::vector whose can be resized, give its size etc directly. "_multidimensional vector_" what you mean, a vector has 1 dimension

Comment: I need it for my work. I'm using multidimensional data for my research and they have different number of dimensions, I just want to make it easier to work with

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are trying to do, but whatever it is, you probably shouldn't. Just use an existing library like Eigen.

Comment: I do not know what it is, but will look at

Comment: @OksiIva it seems you confuse number of dimensions and dimension value, again a vector has 1 dimension whatever its value

Comment: Sorry it looks like I forgot that Eigen only supports 2d tensors (matrices) in the stable version. Arbitrary tensor support is experimental. You may want to look at other libraries such as FTensor. See also https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11276/fast-lightweight-c-tensor-library-for-dimension-agnostic-code