# C++ variable to hold any dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, variables

Is it possible in c++ to create a type of variable that can hold an array with any dimensions? I mean a variable that can store a 1, 2, 3 ... dimensional array.

I guess that it can be made by templates but I could not figure it out how. I would really appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: Could you possibly show an example of the kind of code that you would intend to write with this?

Comment: what about `(void*)`?

Comment: "*Is it possible...?*" The answer is almost always "*Yes,*" but something tells me that won't help you. Can you give us a little more information on what you're trying to do, what you've tried and where it went wrong so that we can give you useful answers?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285352/how-dynamically-filled-multidimensional-vector-without-a-priori-known-its-dimens

Comment: I want to create a function that can multiply arrays and I will need to use it for a lot of different dimensions and I just wondered if I could do it without writing it a separate one for all dimensions.

Comment: Create a class that would do that in runtime.

One possible implementation is to reuse Microsoft's SAFEARRAY if using Windows. 

Edit: If it's for multiplication then you can use well known Matrix classes.

Comment: @AdamVarga what do you mean by *multiply arrays*? Are you talking about something like dot product or matrix multiplication?

Comment: I wanna do something like matrix multiplication but with any array dimension

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358369/c-n-nested-vectors-at-runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to "create a function that can multiply arrays" that will be used "for a lot of different dimensions."

I would deal with this just like I would deal with a `vector` output operator: **use templates with recursion!**

If I wanted to make a function to sum all of the numbers in two `vector`'s when I add them, I could do:

```
template <typename T>
int operator+(std::vector<T> v1, std::vector<T> v2) {
    if(v1.size() != v2.size()) { throw; } //for simplicity
    int sum = 0;
    for(size_t x = 0; x < v1.size(); x++) {
        sum += v1.at(x) + v2.at(x);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note that the magic here is in the line

```
sum += v1.at(x) + v2.at(x);
```

If `v1.at(x)` and `v2.at(x)` are `std::vector`'s, we'll just recursively call this function again. But if they're `int`'s, we'll add them into `sum` and move on.

You can see this in action here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/oa6SY4)

You could do something similar for your array multiplication. Break the problem down into smaller pieces so you can use recursion and let the templates handle the rest!

Answer (score 2):

Do you ever try dynamic memory? In the case below, it creates a two-dimensional array.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

If you want to have a three-dimensional array, maybe you can try to define a two-dimensional array in step two of the above example.

For four-dimensional array, third-dimensional array in step 2.

Or, you can keep using pointer.